# Even light from every angle instead of casting a shadow away from the light source

Tags: lighting, uv-image-editor

I am quite new to Blender and have been following this tutorial [How to Create a Low Poly Tree in 1 Minute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7PdiGXbrD0). Everything went perfect except my tree trunk (circled in red) has even light from every angle, instead of casting a shadow away from the light source. The leaves/branches, on the other hand, appear as expected with the light source (the tutorial uses "cycles" for rendering).

[image: The tree trunk has even light falling on it from all angles]

Here are the nodes (if it helps). The tutorial uses "smart UV".

[image: Tree trunk nodes]

Tutorial for adding UV light to the tree trunk - [0:54](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7PdiGXbrD0&t=54s)

Others: [HDRIS for world building](https://polyhaven.com/a/cliffside), [Branch and Bark Textures](http://bit.ly/3440URc),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using the viewer node, which is an emission node, right before the output. If the material is emissive it wont have shadows on it. Plug the principled BSDF to the output instead